# Markers on Google Maps from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, listview

Hello I have an android app that has a main menu with two buttons. First one gets you on a Google Maps screen and the other one on a screen that shows a listview with information(name, description, coordinates etc) from saved places on my MySQL database. This [example](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html) shows exactly how I populate the lisview from my JSON, I've done it the same way.

Now what I need is to put markers on my map screen from the coordinates of the places I get from my DB. How could I do this? Could I use the same files(AndroidVersion.java, Response.java, LoadJSONTask.java) I used to populate my listview? (see above example)
What should I do to get the coordinates? Can I re-use the files from my other screen or should I start from the beginning? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable with the coordinates you can just call the map and pass them as an argument throw that screen.